# What is equivalent of java socket.setSoLinger(true,0) in Flutter Dart Socket?

Tags: sockets, dart, flutter

In web app I use javacasi to create a socket as;

```
socket = new Socket(host,portNo);
socket.setSoLinger(true,0);
```

Now I am trying to do same in my flutter mobile app.
My question is, what is equivalent of java socket.setSoLinger(true,0) in Flutter Dart Socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an equivalent for now (Dart-2.0.0).

The only [socket option](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/SocketOption-class.html) available is [tcpNoDelay](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/SocketOption/tcpNoDelay-constant.html).

Feel free to [file an issue](http://dartbug.com/new).

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre, before file an issue, is it not setSoLinger(true,0) as same as dart tcpNoDelay?

Comment: After reading a little doc on `SO_LINGER` I don't think it's the same.